# Идеальный алгоритм для рисуемого на канве секундомера

Tags: java, android, алгоритм

Имеются изображения цифр, хочу выводить секунды точка миллисекунды.  Изображения добавил в массив Битмапов(пока толком не применил даже). Сохраняю в переменную системное время в миллисекундах как начало отсчета. И после отнимаю из этого времени текущее время и получаю результат. например 1456 миллисекунд. как же мне объяснить компу ,что надо вывести изображение 1 потом 4,5 и 6. В массиве `Array[1]` это есть изображение единицы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот вариант. В переменно `ms` содержится число

```
String temp = Integer.toString(ms);
int length = temp.length();
int[] digits = new int[length];
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    // вариант для обратного порядка
    // digits[i] = temp.charAt(length - i - 1) - '0';
    digits[i] = temp.charAt(i) - '0';
}
```

В массиве `digits` идут цифры

Comment: Я понимаю, тут делаем из числа строку, int length содержит число символов в строке.  Потом создаем числовой массив длиной в число символов строки и переводим строковые символы в число и сохраняем.  Только не понятно charAt(i) что это за символ и почему минус символ ноль?

Comment: `charAt` - это символ из определенной позиции. все символы цифр в таблице символов идут подряд начиная с 0. и коды цифр идут подряд. предположим 0 - имеет код 60, 1 - 61 и т.д. если из кода цифры вычесть код цифры 0, то получиться сама цифра. 61 (код цифры 1) - 60 (код цифры 0) = 1 (т.е. сама цифра)

Comment: Понял.  Спасибо большое

Answer (score 1):

Возможно, имеет смысл привести `1456` к `String`, разбить `String` на массив и выводить изображение в зависимости от каждого значения в массиве, благо их всего 10 (`0123456789`).